# Inverse Weighted Distribution

Tags: python, probability

I'm looking for a way to do an inverse weighted distribution. Here is my code for a simple linear weighed distribution:

```
total = 0
cumulative_distribution = []

for value in distribution:
    total += value
    cumulative_distribution.append(total)

selected = total * random.random()

index = 0
while cumulative_distribution[index] < selected:
    index += 1

return index
```

How might I inverse this so the items in the list with the smallest weights have the highest probability of being chosen? Is there some way to normalize things and switch them?

Comment: That depends on how you want to weight them. The easiest way would be to replace the weights by `max_weight - weight + 1` or something, so that the previously highest weight becomes 1 and a previously zero weight would be `max_weight`. You could do various other kinds of transformations depending on what properties you want it to have...

Comment: I'm not really concerned about the weights, but rather the actual index selection from the distribution. So long as they achieve a condition where 1 has a much higher chance to be selected than 25, that's good.

Comment: Could you do this without two loop iterations, one to build the distribution, one to rearrange?

Comment: Can't you just reverse the values in `cumulative_distribution` and also change the `while` loop to stop on the inverse condition?

Comment: Couldn't you simply do something like `distribution = [1/x for x in distribution]` then run the current code?

Comment: @Blckknght I would use `1/(x+1)` in case an object has a zero weight.

Comment: @Hooked: Well, with inverse weighting a zero-weight item is probably invalid, so you might not need worry about it. Or if a zero-weighted item should remain zero-weight in the inverse distribution, you could use `[1/x if x else 0 for x in distribution]`. Look Ma, no `ZeroDivisionError`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it really depends on how you want to weight them. Using your statement:

> the smallest weights have the highest probability of being chosen

both @Blckknght and I had the same idea, simply weight each point in the PDF with it's inverse. I suggest weighting them by a parameter like

```
inverse_PDF = 1/(PDF + delta)
```

Where `delta` is a parameter you can control to your tastes. If `delta=0` then any point in the PDF where the original weight is zero will throw a `ZeroDivisionError` which is usually undesirable. Below is some sample code using numpy that implements the above:

```
import numpy as np

# Generate a random points
pts = np.random.normal(size=(10**6,))

# Compute a PDF
PDF,bins = np.histogram(pts, bins=50)

# Normalize (could have used normed=True in hist)
PDF = PDF / np.trapz(PDF, bins[1:])

# Create the inverse distribution
delta = .1
inverse_PDF = 1/(PDF + delta)

# Normalize
inverse_PDF = inverse_PDF / np.trapz(inverse_PDF, bins[1:])

# Plot the results
import pylab as plt
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(bins[1:],PDF,lw=4,alpha=.7)
plt.title("Original Distribution")
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(bins[1:],inverse_PDF,lw=4,alpha=.7)
plt.title(r"'Inverse' Distribution with $\delta=%.3f$" % delta)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]